# Downsides of planned suicide

Tags: dead-cells

I'm at the point now where I can beat the Incomplete One about 80% of the time. I'm having major issues with the Fog Fjord though. The first few times I got there I decided to try and beat the level, but after 10 minutes I ended up doing something stupid and dying and losing everything, which proved to be a waste of time (usually getting trapped by biters after killing a Host).

I've since decided that until I've progressed my guy further, or manage to put together a perfect inventory before getting there, I'll kill myself as soon as I get to the Fog Fjord to save myself the time and effort. I do try every few times I get there to "test the waters" to see where my character is at, but it's consistently proving to be a difficult area.

Besides obviously incrementing my death count (which I'm not concerned about), are there any problems with my plan? Are there any known hidden mechanics that punish death?

Comment: What weapons do you favor?  You should be able to get through Fog Fjord with relatively few unlocks, as long as you focus your stat increases.

Comment: @mmatthews Blood sword and shield. I actually just tried again last night by skipping most fights in the Fjord and got to the Clock Tower. I got wrecked there though because of the Huge sword guys + Heavy Grenade guys being together everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll lose cells and gold, as well as not practicing dealing with the enemies in that area.
As a side note, you may also want to try going through the Old Sewers.  That is another way of progress, and can unlock other runes through that path that will help you navigate the levels.

Comment: I have the 15k money unlock, so losing money isn't an issue. Maybe I'll justkeep chopping away at it. And I've never seen the Old Sewers. What area is before it?

Comment: The door is in the first area, so instead of going to Promenade of the Condemned, you can go to the Old Sewers.  You'll need the rune that can grow vines from the green masses on the floor first, but I forgot where that rune comes from.

Comment: Do you mean the Toxic Sewers? And ya, I've gone through both. I alternate. I haven't found any other runes in the toxic area though.

Comment: Ah sorry, Old Sewers is after Toxic Sewers.  I get those mixed up.